# PostgreSQL - how to render date in different time zone?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

My server is in Central Time. I would like to render timestamps using Eastern time.

For instance, I would like to render `2012-05-29 15:00:00` as `2012-05-29 16:00:00 EDT`.

How can I achieve it?

`to_char('2012-05-29 15:00:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'EST5EDT', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')` gives `2012-05-29 16:00:00` (no zone).

`to_char('2012-05-29 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'EST5EDT', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')` gives `2012-05-29 14:00:00 CDT` (wrong).

This one works, but it's so ridiculously complicated there must be an easier way: `replace(replace(to_char(('2012-05-29 15:00:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'EST5EDT')::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ'), 'CST', 'EST'), 'CDT', 'EDT')`

Comment: How is the server supposed to know which time zone *abbreviation* you want to display? It only knows the time zone *offset*

Comment: Time zone information is not black magic. There is no technical reason that would make it impossible (or even hard) to say that 5/29 is DST in Eastern Time. In fact, PG knows it all - `to_char(x, 'TZ')` differentiates CST from CDT correctly, and `at time zone EST5EDT` respects DST as well. The only bit I'm missing is elegant rendering using this information.

Comment: The problem here is in the bizarre choice of the Postgres devs that `timestamp with time zone at _zone_` should convert the time zones, but return `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: @lanzz There are many bizarre places around converting `timestamp` <-> `timestamptz` and using `at time zone`, but is there really no built-in way to render different time zone, like `fmt_date(x, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ', 'EST5EDT')`?

Comment: I've pondered that same issue at some point in the past, and as far as I can remember, couldn't find a sane solution. Probably best you can do is manage timezones and formatting on application side instead of in the database, though this is not really an answer to your question.

Comment: @lanzz Disappointing as it is, "not possible" is also a valid answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The key is to switch the local timezone to the desired display timezone, for the duration of the transaction:

```
begin;
set local timezone to 'EST5EDT';
select to_char('2012-05-29 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'CDT',
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ');
end;
```

The result is:

> 2012-05-29 16:00:00 EDT

Note that with `set [local] timezone` it is required to use full time zone names instead of abbreviations (for instance, CST would not work). Look up in the `pg_timezone_names` view for valid choices.

To use that method in a context similar to a to_char() call, I believe this function does the job:

```
CREATE FUNCTION display_in_other_tz(
      in_t timestamptz,
      in_tzname text,
      in_fmt text) RETURNS text
AS $$
DECLARE
 v text;
 save_tz text;
BEGIN
  SHOW timezone into save_tz;
  EXECUTE 'SET local timezone to ' || quote_literal(in_tzname);
  SELECT to_char(in_t, in_fmt) INTO v;
  EXECUTE 'SET local timezone to ' || quote_literal(save_tz);
  RETURN v;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Your *first* answer is correct. As I understand the question, the OP wants the system to output 'EDT' or 'EST' depending on the timestamp. Your later addition would fail in this respect.

Comment: Ok I can see that I misunderstood that part of the problem. Changing my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 Very clean now. Your last version is also an improvement in that it resets the current `timezone`. I was assuming the default `timezone`. And I like the `SHOW timezone INTO`.

Comment: this makes me appreciate how concise is the shell, e.g: `TZ=Australia/Perth date`

Answer (score 4):

> In fact, PG knows it all - to_char(x, 'TZ') differentiates CST from
>   CDT correctly, and at time zone EST5EDT respects DST as well.

When dealing with a timestamp Postgres knows:

- The setting of the GUC [`timezone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE).
- The [data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).
- The *value*, which is the same count of seconds since '1970-1-1 0:0 UTC' for `timestamp` and `timestamptz`. (Or, to be precise: UT1.)
- Details about other time zones in your [date/time configuration files](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datetime-config-files.html)

When interpreting input, Postgres uses information about the provided time zone.
When rendering a timestamp value, Postgres uses the *current* `timezone` setting, but time zone *offset*, *abbreviation* or *name* are only used to compute the correct *value* on input. They are **not saved**. It is **impossible** to extract that information later. More details in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860):

Your "correct" example is ***almost*** correct. `TZ` of `to_char()` returns 'CDT' for timestamps that fall in the daylight saving periods of Central Time and 'CST' else. Eastern Time (`EST` /`EDT`) switches daylight saving hours at the same **local** time - I quote Wikipedia:

> The time is adjusted at 2:00 AM local time.

The two time zones are **out of sync** during two hours per year. Of course, this can never affect a timestamp at `15:00` or `16:00`, only around `02:00`.

A fully correct solution - much like what @Daniel already posted, slightly simplified:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL timezone to 'EST5EDT';
SELECT to_char('2012-05-29 15:00 CST6CDT'::timestamptz
             , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')
RESET timezone;  -- only if more commands follow in this transactions
END;
```

> The effects of SET LOCAL last only till the end of the current transaction.

[The manual about `SET LOCAL`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set.html)

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. I asked about date rendering, not conversion. I know how to convert to `timestamp`, what I'm looking for is a way to render a `varchar` with different time zone name in a general case.

Comment: @KonradGarus: I didn't have more time earlier today. I think I understand more clearly what you are after now and also why your solution is almost, but not quite, correct.