# How to convert timestamp field to ISO 8601 string in a given time zone?

Tags: postgresql

I have a "timestamp with time zone" field in a table.
I need to return is as iso 8601 string in a give time zone.
The closest thing that I managed to do is this:

```
select to_char(crtdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MSOF:"00"')  from t1
```

But it returns a timestamp in a system default time zone (UTC) i.e. something like this:

```
2017-07-12T02:46:26.194+00:00
```

while I need it be formatted for a specific time zone.
E.g.

```
2017-07-12T14:46:26.194+12:00
```

for "Pacific/Auckland".

Can someone please advise how this can be achieved?

we are on PG v 9.6.

Thank you,

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this will give a timestamp in Postgres format, not ISO 8601

Comment: do you need to get that value for current `timezone` GUC setting (set by `set timezone = ...;`) or you want to dynamically (w/o touching GUC) get ISO8601 values for various timezones?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name internally, there is no any format, that's right, but there is a default output format, and this is what matters here. What is more important, your comments lead to not the direction the topic starter needs -- `at time zone ...` will give you a value w/o any timezone information, while the author needs ISO 8601, with hours shift (however, `at time zone ...` can help to build a proper custom function)

Comment: If you have any doubts that "there is" output format – https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT "The output format of the date/time types can be set to one of the four styles ISO 8601, SQL (Ingres), traditional POSTGRES (Unix date format), or German."

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10797720/330315 or maybe [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/257-Working-with-Timezones.html)

Comment: Well, formally you are right, but this discussion can lead us to things «3 can be less than 2 if you ("your SQL client") redefine the numbers and use them in the order 1, 3, 2, 4, 5...». If an SQL client doesn't use `datestyle` and `timezone` to display timestamps -- that's ф bad SQL client, at least for work with Postgres.

Comment: @Nick: shrug. I prefer SQL clients where I can specifically configure the format of the display in the client.

Comment: BTW, the question is not the same. You refer to very similar one, but again, here the author needs a special format.

Comment: The question is not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with GUC parameters `datestyle` and `timezone` inside a function to get what you want. Here is an example (however, it returns microseconds, so probably you'll need to tune it a bit):

```
create or replace function timestamp_iso8601(ts timestamptz, tz text) returns text as $$
declare
  res text;
begin
  set datestyle = 'ISO';
  perform set_config('timezone', tz, true);
  res := ts::timestamptz(3)::text;
  reset datestyle;
  reset timezone;
  return replace(res, ' ', 'T') || ':00';
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

Results:

```
test=# select timestamp_iso8601(now()::timestamptz, 'Europe/Moscow');
       timestamp_iso8601
-------------------------------
 2017-07-12T08:56:58.692985+03:00

test=# select timestamp_iso8601(now()::timestamptz, 'Pacific/Auckland');
       timestamp_iso8601
-------------------------------
 2017-07-12T17:59:05.863483+12:00
(1 row)
```

Update: edited. You can use `timestamptz(3)`, specifying the *precision* (by default, it will go with microseconds, while `3` will keep only milliseconds). Alternatively, you can use `res := to_char(ts::timestamptz, 'IYYY-MM-DDT HH24:MI:SS:MSOF');` instead of `::timestamptz(3)::text` conversion chain, and in this case `(3)` will not be needed.

Comment: Not really correct attaching the time zone offset minutes as `|| ':00'`. this approach does not take in to account that there are places like Sri Lanka where the offset is UTC+05:30.