# Postgresql select output date with missing timezone offset

Tags: postgresql

I've got a hard time with postgresql and timezones.

The Postgresql server is in **UTC time zone**.
I want to perform a query that returns the date in **another timezone with the timezone offset**.

I can perform a query that returns the date in a timezone but **I'm missing the timezone offset**

```
base=# SET timezone to 'utc';
SET
base=# select now();
             now              
------------------------------
 2018-04-20 14:58:22.68038+00
(1 row)

base=# SET timezone to 'Europe/Paris';
SET
base=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2018-04-20 16:58:29.614383+02
(1 row)


base=# SET timezone to 'utc';
SET
base=# select now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2018-04-20 16:59:03.146917   -- missing timezone offset here
(1 row)
```

**Expected result**

```
base=# SET timezone to 'utc';
SET
base=# select now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris'; --I'm missing something here, I guess
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2018-04-20 16:59:03.146917+02   -- That's what I want
(1 row)
```

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you use `AT TIME ZONE`, PG returns a timestamp without time zone. If you cast it to back to a timestamp with time zone, you get your expected result:

`SELECT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris')::TIMESTAMPTZ;`

Result:

`2018-04-20 18:15:26.165+02`

---

How do you get the +02 without setting the timezone? Here's the problem: `NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris'` returns the current time in the specified time zone (without an offset), and casting it back to `TIMESTAMPTZ` gives you the offset of the current time zone (of your PG session) based on UTC. Since 'Europe/Paris' is +02 from UTC, if you've set your time zone to 'Europe/Paris', the offset you get in a `TIMESTAMPTZ` is +02. If your current time zone setting is UTC, your offset is +00.

How to get the offset no matter what your PG session's time zone setting, without explicitly setting the time zone? I would like to think there's a better way to get the offset, but without knowing one, here's one way: calculate the offset, format it, append it to the timestamp without time zone.

`SELECT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris')::TEXT || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(hour FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' - NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), 'FMSG00')`

Result: `2018-04-21 15:12:42.658+02`, and I get the same result no matter the current timezone.

Comment: Thanks, it gives the expected result only if we use `set time zone 'Europe/Paris';` Then we just have to use: ` SELECT (NOW())::TIMESTAMPTZ;` to get: `2018-04-21 13:31:12.088679+02`. I would like to just get this result without explicitly setting the timezone with `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris';`

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for for a couple of hours

Answer (score 0):

- Some timezone have an offset in 30 or 45 minutes.
  Using `TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(hour FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' - NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')` exclude this use case.
- Did you consider to use `SET LOCAL TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris';` in a dedicated function ? According to the documentation :

> If SET LOCAL is used within a function that has a SET option for the same variable (see CREATE FUNCTION), the effects of the SET LOCAL command disappear at function exit

This other reply seem's fitting your requirement :  [How to convert timestamp field to ISO 8601 string in a given time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048787/how-to-convert-timestamp-field-to-iso-8601-string-in-a-given-time-zone)